# .NET Web Core 5 API - How can I consume Kafka messages from my Linux server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, apache-kafka, producer-consumer

I made a Linux virtual machine that is running Kafka. I tested the producer and was able to consume it from my other computer. Now I want to make a consumer that runs in my API that I'm working on.

I'm trying to follow some tutorials, but they are confusing. I want to just run a consumer that will read the messages from the producer in my project. I downloaded the Confluent.Kafka package. Then I tried making a Services/ProcessOrdersService.cs file like so:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System.Threading;
using POS.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Confluent.Kafka;

namespace POS.Services
{
    public class ProcessOrdersService
    {

        private readonly ConsumerConfig consumerConfig;

        public ProcessOrdersService(ConsumerConfig consumerConfig)
        {
            this.consumerConfig = consumerConfig;
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm confusing on what to do after this? Can anyone point me in the right direction? I've tried looking at some tutorials but I don't understand where things are supposed to go within my Web Core 5 API project.

Thank you for any help. :D

Comment: Do you know [Dependency injection in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0)? This can be a good start.

Comment: You've only stored a config here. Where is your actual consumer object? That's the "next step", but if you actually intend to display the records as part of some api, then that'll be more difficult as you need to maintain state of the consumer offsets across api instances

Answer (score 0):

You may find [my article](https://kamil-zakiev.medium.com/kafka-consumer-api-c-117ccb514971) helpful: I provided comprehensive instructions on how to consume from C# and explained a couple of subtle points.

If you have any questions, feel free to ask!